# Cannot find controller in scenebuilder 2.0

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

Just wondered if I could get some help as I'm currently using SceneBuilder 2.0 to build a GUI for my software. I've got an issue however where I am unable to link the [FXML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS5lj.png) file with the Controller even though they are currently within the same folder in the project [Screenshot within Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U58sx.png).

Any help for this issue will much appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: Please find below the Java Controller class as requested:

```
package rucmView;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;

public class GherkinController {

    @FXML
    private MenuItem exit;

    @FXML
    void ExitApplication(ActionEvent event) {

    }

}
```

Please also find the FXML class as requested:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" layoutY="31.0" prefHeight="570.0" prefWidth="600.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="403.0" prefWidth="174.0">
               <children>
                  <GridPane layoutX="1.0" layoutY="114.0" prefHeight="324.0" prefWidth="174.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="Load Test Case" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Create Defs" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="Exit Application" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="128.0" text="Seleniun View" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
               </children></AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="385.0" prefWidth="416.0">
               <children>
                  <TextArea prefHeight="251.0" prefWidth="416.0" text="Sample Gherkin Script:&#10;&#10;Feature: Openwebpage&#10;This is going to be a test to ensure that the selenium &#10;webdriver is able to open up the tests as intended.&#10;&#10;Scenario: Successfully opening Website.&#10;&#10;Given user navigates to Website&#10;&#10;Then navigate to Link-1 Homepage &#10;&#10;" wrapText="true" />
                  <TextArea layoutY="262.0" prefHeight="296.0" prefWidth="416.0" text="Test Case Validation:&#10;&#10;Checks to see if the Gherkin script is syntactically correct and valid." wrapText="true" />
               </children></AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
      <MenuBar prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="600.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save Results" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="exit" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ExitApplication" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="View">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Selenium" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Gherkin/RUCM" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Selenium">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Chrome" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="FireFox" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Guide" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you please post FXML and Controller class declaration?

Comment: Hi Bjørn, just added them now into the post, the controller class is public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure the controller is `public`.
- `fx:controller` requires the full package path to the controller class.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. The fxml file is not able to detect my controller class when mentioned inside `fx:controller` 

My controller is public too

Answer (score -1):

Your Controller class and your fxml file should be in same package. Then you can find option for controller class in SceneBuilder. Or you can add manually in fxml file like: `fx:controller="app.fxml.PropertiesDemoController"`

EX:

`<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.fxml.PropertiesDemoController">`